# Bluetooth communication between Processing Desktop and Android(Not Processing)

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, processing

What I'm doing is communication between

**Desktop(Windows 8) Processing(2.2.1) Application  <----  Android application(Not made by Processing, it's made on Android Studio)**

I need to send data to desktop from android application (one side communication).

From android..
First, I'm getting already paired device. It means that before executing both application, I will pair desktop and android device already.
Bluetooth connection and sending outstream is on child thread.

```
    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = btAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
        for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {

            Log.i(TAG, device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
            targetDevice = device;
            break;
        }
    }else{
        Log.i(TAG, "No paired device found!");
    }
```

And then, I connect it

```
    BluetoothSocket tmp = null;

    // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the
    // given BluetoothDevice
    try {
        tmp = targetDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        Method m = targetDevice.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[]{int.class});
        tmp = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(targetDevice, 1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "create() failed", e);
    }
    btSocket = tmp;

    if (btSocket != null){
        // Socket is created

        // try to connect the socket
        BluetoothConnectionThread thread = new BluetoothConnectionThread(btSocket);
        thread.start();
    }
```

From logcat(Log.i), I can see connection is successfully established. It seems that there is no problem on android side.

I'm using Serial Port Protocol UUID which is

```
private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
```

And from Android side, it's completely ready to write any byte[].. and when I press dummy button on android, device sends dummy bytes to outputstream. I think it has no problem here on Android side..

**Now, on desktop processing**(Windows 8, processing 2.2.1 - I HAVE TO USE processing 2.0, there is no other option for some reason.), I have no any clue what I have to now.. I searched in google a lot but I could not find any clue. Now, I'm trying to use processing Serial library like

```
println(Serial.list());
```

but it gives nothing... So, I tried to initialize Serial object by

```
Serial port = new Serial(this, "/dev/rfcomm0", 115200);
```

but it gives error

**Error opening serial port /dev/rfcomm0:Port busy**

Is there any other way to read socket buffer(instream) which comes from Android on processing desktop?

**I am sure that this is not bluetooth driver issue because I installed the recentest driver for my desktop(Qualcomm Atheros AR3012 Bluetooth 4.0 + HS)**

Just for reference..desktop is actually laptop with bluetooth(ASUS UX21E) and Android device is Galaxy Tab S(267.2mm, Octa-Core 2560x1600).

I think I have not enough knowledge about bluetooth... Please lead me to some way...